# VSCode server unexpected "Missing GLIBC >= 2.28"

Tags: visual-studio-code, ssh

I'm connecting to a server via ssh using VSCode.
The server has Ubuntu 18.04, and until yesterday night, it was working fine, however since this morning, I get the following error (checking the logs in `~/.vscode-server`):

> Warning: Missing GLIBC >= 2.28! from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.27.so
> Error: Missing required dependencies. Please refer to our FAQ https://aka.ms/vscode-remote/faq/old-linux for additional information.

I checked and the library indeed is an older version, however it's strange to me that until yesterday it worked

Has VSCode updated the server extension on the server in the background silently or what? Anybody with this problem?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There was an update released last night that drops support of older glibc versions. The official workaround is to downgrade to VSCode 1.85, as described [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/203967#issuecomment-1923440629).

Comment: That's why I turn back to VIM, which never let you down!

Comment: Downgrading to 1.85.2 solve this temporay issue. Waiting for a fix for 1.86.

Comment: Fixed in 1.86.1 https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/204344

Comment: Downvoted because better solution is available now. That is to UPgrade

Answer (score 4):

On some devices, the script that is used to determine versions does not work correctly. I haven't had the time to understand why that is, but there's another workaround.

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/main/resources/server/bin/helpers/check-requirements-linux.sh#L16

`touch /tmp/vscode-skip-server-requirements-check`

Creating this file will bypass the requirements check.

In my case, I'm running on a Synology DS920+, and I actually do have the correct version of glibc, but due to synology's lack of shipping a `getconf` command, the script fails.

YMMV, but for me, creating that file has solved the problem.

Comment: extra thanks goes to you beside the upvote :D i also have the 920+ and creating this file fixed the issue for me (beside the version upgrade i guess)

Comment: Even this workaround does not work for me, but I don't have the server version, I have the regular one... not sure how this can changes anything

Answer (score 2):

This has been fixed `1.86.1`

The remote server will now check the GLIBC version and run the legacy server for older GLIBCs.

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/204344

Comment: I just got the tarball of the 1.87.1 and still have the issue. (Didn't test the version between 1.85 and 1.87.1). However, I don'' use the *server* version, I use the regular one. Maybe I missed something but I didn't get the difference...

Answer (score 0):

Works with this version https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_85.
I got the same error. Resolved with November 2023 (version 1.85) version [I used Downloads: Windows: x64 Arm64 ]